# Wordpress CSS: Center Iframe Object

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to center this: https://www.nologo.surf/4-fun/ on 360º image isnt center...

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your div with the class `threesixty-image` add this:

```
.threesixty-image {
    margin: auto;
}
```

I tested in browser and that should center it for you.

Comment: Working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Just add this code in your CSS**

`.threesixty-image {
    margin:0 auto;
}`